# Using variables in a filter string

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subform that returns data from a table. However I want to further filter this data by using the filter property.

I have a group of radio buttons, combo boxes and a case statement which sets the variables I want to use to the correct values depending on the radio button selection

My code for filling the variables works perfectly but I cannot use vba to set the filter unless I manually type the string that I want.

I assume that my issue is that my filter string is syntactically incorrect but I am unsure of how. Probably something to do with text delimiters.

```
Forms![frmPendingActions]![qryPendingAction subform].Form.Filter = Filterby = FilterCrit
Forms![frmPendingActions]![qryPendingAction subform].Form.FilterOn = True
```

Assume for this question that Filterby=[Reporter] and FilterCrit= Fake Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I think the problem is to do with text delimiters.  The code should look similar to the following:

```
Forms![frmPendingActions]![qryPendingAction subform].Form.Filter = "[Reporter] ='" &  FilterCrit  & "'"
```

The filter should be built exactly the same as a where clause without the word where.  If the column you are filtering by has a text datatype then the criteria needs to be enclosed in single or double quotes.  If the column is a date datatype then it needs to be enclosed in #.  If the column is a number datatype then it does not need to be enclosed.

If you do not always wish to filter by the Reporter column then you can build a string using if statements or select case statements and then apply that string to the form filter.

For example:

```
If [somecondition] Then
   strFilter="[Reporter]='" & FilterCrit & "'"
Else
   strFilter="[ID]=" & 0
End If
Forms![frmPendingActions]![qryPendingAction subform].Form.Filter = strFilter
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is promising. The filter appears to work correctly but I think you may have misunderstood my question a little.

The column that I want to filter by is also a variable, how would I handle that?

Comment: The column is a text datatype by the way

Comment: Nevermind, I adapted the rest of my code around you statement.